# how to completely remove mysql community workbench from my system

Tags: apt, mysql, uninstall, mysql-workbench

I installed an old version of MySQL Workbench which was not compatible two years ago. Recently, I decided to install MySQL Server 8.0.24 using apt but I could not connect to MySQL Workbench Community via the GUI. I now installed another MySQL Workbench Community but I still could not connect. Then I uninstalled the MySQL Workbench Community. Now I want to uninstall it completely both the programs so that I can start afresh.

Answer (score 12):

Based on [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-linux-uninstalling.html), you can uninstall MySQL Workstation like this:

0. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
1. Uninstall the package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove mysql-workbench-community
   ```
2. Check if there is a `/mysql` or `/workbench` directory in your home directory, and delete it if the files are no longer needed.

If you had installed the snap version of MySQL Workbench, then you can do this:

0. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
1. Remove the snap:

   ```
   sudo snap remove mysql-workbench-community
   ```

That should be it

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!